# How can I send a request to API with on click of my button in React hooks?

Tags: reactjs

So I currently have this code that has a useEffect() that shows the data from the API every time. I refresh, but I'm trying to make that data display only when I click on my button. I'm not too sure where to go with my code.

```
      import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
      import './App.css';
      import axios from 'axios';

      function App() {
        const [image, setImage] = useState(false);
   
      // I tried to put a onclick function, but not sure what to add here
        const handleChange = ()
      => {
      setImage(true)
      }
      

      // this code displays my data on refresh
      useEffect(() => {
        axios
          .get(
            'https://api.com'
          )
          .then(res => {
             setImage ?
            setImage(res.data.faces[0].urls[4][512]) : console.log('nothing')
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err.message);
          });
      }, []);

        return (
          <div className='App'>
            <h1>Photo Generator</h1>
            <img src={image} />
            <button onClick={handleChange}>Show new Image</button>
          </div>
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState('');
  const [displayImage, setDisplayImage] = useState('none');

  const handleChange = () => {
    setDisplayImage('flex');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('https://api.com')
      .then((res) => {
        setImage
          ? setImage(res.data.faces[0].urls[4][512])
          : console.log('nothing');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Photo Generator</h1>
      <div style={{display: displayImage}}>
        <img style src={image} />
      </div>

      <button onClick={() => handleChange()}>Show new Image</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You could also do

```
<button onClick={() => setDisplayImage('flex')}>Show new Image</button>
```

Comment: why did you remove the useEffect hook?

Comment: I adjusted the answer. Should be good now. @designxd10

Comment: you just copied my code exactly? there's nothing that fixes my issue?

Comment: I'm trying to receive an image so it says "true". is error for non-boolean attribute src. So how would I update state for a non-boolean (image)? I tried to pass in the res.data.faces[0].urls[4][512] but it says data is not define, which would come from my API, but I can only add that in my useEffect hook

Comment: @designxd10 my bad I misunderstood this. Check it now. Now it will call the API on button press and then set the state like you are in your use effect.

Comment: what's the point of having the api called twice? the useEffect will always run on page refresh now, which defeats the purpose of the button

Comment: Your question is kind of confusing on what you are trying to do. What exactly do you want to happen when the person clicks the button?

Comment: right now the page displays a random image whenever I refresh with my useEffect hook. I want to only display the random image when I click my button. I included the button and handleChange code to show my attempt, but that code doesn't work properly

Comment: @designxd10 got it I updated with a way that will do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your code.
Try this code, let me know if it works for you. :)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(false);

  // I tried to put a onclick function, but not sure what to add here
  const handleChange = () => {
    axios
      .get("https://api.com")
      .then(res => {
        const uri = res.data.faces[0].urls[4][512];
        if (uri) {
          setImage(uri);
        } else {
          console.log("nothing");
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Photo Generator</h1>
      {image && <img src={image} alt="yourImage" />}
      <button type="button" onClick={handleChange}>
        Show new Image
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You don't need to use useEffect Hook in this case.
also don't need to check setImage inside of API callback function.

Comment: looks like this works. Do you know how I can add additional data from the API to display to my screen? for example this code shows gender `res.data.faces[0].meta.gender[0]` so how would I show that below my image?